# Programmatically change activity background image within OnCreate

Tags: android, image, oncreate

I have made one of my apps compatible with Android versions prior to 3.2 using Action Bar Sherlock. The background image I have used for each activity within this app does not look good in the earlier versions of Android.

Therefore, I would like to remove the background image for each activity in the app ONLY if the Android version being used is below 3.2. I believe I can implement this within OnCreate, but I'm not exactly sure how. All of the activity attributes have been set in the layout files themselves. Can someone give me example code on how to programmatically change the background within OnCreate for the earlier Android versions? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Check [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION.html)

Do something like:

```
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR2){
    // remove background picture 
}
```

Comment: This won't work exactly as `Build.VERSION.SDK_INT` is, strangely enough, an integer! Refer to the list of version codes to find the value you need. In this case, Android 3.2 == Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR2 == 13.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 13) { 
yourlayout.setBackgroundResource(resourceID);     
}
```

Comment: This has the same problem as the other answer! Come on guys.